# what is the correct configuration for slf4j in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, slf4j

have been having this rather ubiquitous problem with `slf4j`, the logging abstraction of logging abstractions of logging abstractions :-)

#### 1) My maven tests were failing:

`[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?`

#### 2) Digging deeper into the failing tests:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. 
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

There are multiple bindings, by analysing the dependencies with maven, I discovered this:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
```

So now I know that `spring-boot-start-actuator` is the root cause of the problem, but including starter logging, and logback-classic **spring boot actuator** appears to have **incorrect dependencies**.

My fix is this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

By removing *logback-classic* my tests complete, however the application fails to start.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

> What is the correct configuration for slf4j in spring?

*edit*

spring batch seems to also include slf4j-log4j

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-resources:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
```

By removing spring batch admin, I now get this message.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/craig/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testharness</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TestHarness</name>
    <description>Service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
            <version>[0.1,)</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datadoghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>dd-trace-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
            <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-encryption-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.592</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.448</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.448</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ssm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ssm</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.449</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.449</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.34.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.449</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.docusign</groupId>
            <artifactId>docusign-esign-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>report</id>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.1</version>                        <!-- or newer version -->
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>                            <!-- depending on your project -->
                            <target>1.8</target>                            <!-- depending on your project -->
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <path>
                                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                                </path>
                                <!-- other annotation processors -->
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I am just hacking now, but this is the current state:
Now there are **three**...

```
LF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/craig/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.25/slf4j-nop-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/craig/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.25/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/craig/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
```

Comment: Please show the complete pom, for me Spring Boot 2.0.x and 2.1.x are running just fine both in Java 8 and 11 with Actuator und slf4j

Comment: It is recommended to use slf4j with logback. There is no configuration for slf4j, it is used as a library, you have to make configuration for logback.xml.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Spring boot, you have to exclude both **logback-classic** and **log4j-over-slf4j**. I would suggest to use logback binding. After excluding these log binding, check in the IDEs like Eclipse or Intellij about the maven dependencies. If you find logback.jar, then create a **logback.xml** and put inside the resources directory. You can check more details on logback in the following link.

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html